# rendering parties of other site with express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a basic Express application with one function that uses nodejs request and takes some divs using selectors. After that, I want to render this with jade.

```
var express = require('express');
var voc = require('vocabulaire');
var async = require('async');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Espace de la diffusion'});
});

var result;
router.get('/search/:mot', function (req, res) {
    async.series([
        function () {
            result = main(['conj', req.params.mot]);
            console.log('in 1');
        },
        function () {

            res.render('index', {title: 'Espace de la diffusion', data: result});
            res.send(html);
            console.log('in 2');
        },
    ]);    
});    

module.exports = router;


var request = require('request')
    , cheerio = require('cheerio');

function doit(verbe, result) {
    var url = 'http://www.babla.ru/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/' + verbe;

    request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var temps = $('.span4.result-left h5');
        if (temps.length == 0) {
            console.log('results not found');
        }
        else {
            console.log('result found');
            debugger;
            return $('.span4.result-left');
        }
    });
}


function main(arg) {
    switch (arg[0]) {
        case 'conj':
            return doit(arg[1]);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('unknown parameter');
            break;
    }
}
```

I used async library for be sure that my result is ready to be rendered but in console I see next:

GET /search/est - - ms - -
in 1
result found

and debugger followed me to nodejs function makeTick()..
I don't know what to do.. help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async.series()` functions are missing the `callback` parameter that you need to call in order for the next function to execute. However, you don't really need `async` to just do a single async task:

```
main(['conj', req.params.mot], function(err, result) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Espace de la diffusion', err: err, data: result});
});

// ...

function doit(verbe, result, callback) {
    var url = 'http://www.babla.ru/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/' + verbe;

    request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err)
          return callback && callback(err);

        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var temps = $('.span4.result-left h5');
        if (temps.length == 0) {
            callback && callback();
        }
        else {
            callback && callback(null, $('.span4.result-left'));
        }
    });
}


function main(arg, callback) {
    switch (arg[0]) {
        case 'conj':
            doit(arg[1], callback);
            break;
        default:
            callback && callback(new Error('unknown parameter'));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined is not a function on a callback